# Many SQL rows into one

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I've got a stored procedure which joins a number of tables to produce a large resultset which is then returned to my application. The application in turn loops through the results and combines rows on a particular ID and chooses data per row to include in a new object. This is perhaps easiest to explain using an example:

```
Inspection, Desc,         Value
1,          Description1, 3       
1,          Description2, 2
1,          Description3, 5
```

This is in code turned into

```
Inspection, Description1, Description2, Description3
1,          3,            2,            5
```

The point of this is to have one row per inspection item with item description as headers and value as the cell value for inspection row and header. This is then exported to Excel.

The question is: how do I do this in SQL Server, as in expanding my SP to return a lot fewer but "wider" rows with a lot more columns?

Another complication is that one inspection may have rows which another one lacks, in that case the solution is to add an empty value or a '-'.

P.S. This is using Sql Server 2012.

Comment: use `pivot`, it will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to do this dynamically, without having to know what all of the `Desc` values are, you can build your pivot query and use `Exec()` or `Execute sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Build your column headers based on Distinct Desc values
SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME([Desc])
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [Desc] FROM tbl) t
ORDER BY [Desc]

--Build your pivot query
SET @Sql = '
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        tbl
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Value])
        FOR [Desc] IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

If you want `-` for null values, you'll need to create another variable to hold the conversion scripts for the `Select` part of your sql.

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnAliases NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Build your pivot columns based on Distinct Desc values
SELECT  @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME([Desc])
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [Desc] FROM tbl) t
ORDER BY [Desc]

--Build your column headers, replacing NULL with -
SELECT  @ColumnAliases = COALESCE(@ColumnAliases + ',', '') 
            + 'COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,' + QUOTENAME([Desc]) + '),''-'') AS ' + QUOTENAME([Desc])
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [Desc] FROM tbl) t
ORDER BY [Desc]


--Build your pivot query
SET @Sql = '
    SELECT 
        Inspection,'
        + @ColumnAliases + '
    FROM
        tbl
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Value])
        FOR [Desc] IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks. This one provided the most hints to be able to solve my issue, marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mssql 2005+. You can use a pivot like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Inspection INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(100),Value INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'Description1', 3),     
(1,'Description2', 2),
(1,'Description3', 5)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
SELECT
    tbl.Inspection,
    tbl.[Desc],
    tbl.Value
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Value)
    FOR [Desc] IN ([Description1],[Description2],[Description3])
)AS pvt
```

**Result:**

```
Inspection, Description1, Description2, Description3
1           3             2             5
```

**Edit**

As juharr said in the comment:

The resulting column names (values in the table) are when building the query. Which might require another initial query to get

**Edit 2**

If you are not using mssql 2005+. Or want to have and alternitive explanation. Please see the following query:

```
SELECT
    tbl.Inspection,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Desc]='Description1' THEN tbl.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Description1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Desc]='Description2' THEN tbl.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Description2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Desc]='Description3' THEN tbl.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Description3
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.Inspection
```

This do not requiere a pivot and can be use on most of RDMS out there

Comment: Should note this requires that the OP knows what the resulting column names (values in the table) are when building the query.  Which might require another initial query to get.

Comment: @juharr : Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use Sql Server `Pivot`. It converts rows into columns. You can have an easiest start by [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query).

Comment: That's as sloppy as an answer can be. You should provide a full answer, not just "name-drop" a feature/keyword/mechanism and be done with it.

Comment: @Amit I would definitely do, if there was any code or something which I could explain. This was the best i could answer for this **get a suggestion** type of question.

Comment: I think you could either provide a minimal example to show how that would work provided the sample data in the question, or I'd comment on the question itself, explaining why such questions are inappropriate for SO (because they lead to answers like yours), and maybe even vote for close. But that's just my opinion... :-) (P.S. See @Arion's answer)

Comment: That's alright for me, I'll give it a go soon and accept your answer if it solves what I've tried to ask :) If not I'll have to rephrase the question.

Comment: Agree with that sample data. Will do it in the future :)